# Laravel 5.2 - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - using phpunit

Tags: php, api, laravel, testing, phpunit

I get the above error when testing my application with phpunit command.

```
public function testProductCreationFailsWhenNameNotProvided()
{
    $product = factory(\App\Product::class)->make(['name' => '']);

    $this->post(route('api.products.store'), $product->jsonSerialize())
        ->seeJson(['name' => ['The name field is required.']]) /*line 86*/
        ->assertResponseStatus(422);
}
```

The full error report is here:

```
There was 1 error:
1) ExampleTest::testProductCreationFailsWhenNameNotProvided
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
C:\xampp\htdocs\product-  service\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Arr.php:494
C:\xampp\htdocs\product-service\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:231
C:\xampp\htdocs\product-service\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:257
C:\xampp\htdocs\product-service\tests\ExampleTest.php:86
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 43, Errors: 1.
```

I confess that this code is not originally mine - it is copied from a Laravel tutorial. It worked fine there.
Unfortunately the answer to this related question did not help me either.
[Laravel 5.1 + PHPunit - API test returns always invalid argument error foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921451/laravel-5-1-phpunit-api-test-returns-always-invalid-argument-error-foreach/31940167#31940167)

I tried to modify it in order to pass an json array as a parameter

```
public function testProductCreationFailsWhenNameNotProvided()
    {
        $product = factory(\App\Product::class)->make(['name' => '']);

        $this->post(route('api.products.store'), $product->jsonSerialize())
            ->seeJson(json_encode(array('name' => ['The name field is required.'])))
            ->assertResponseStatus(422);
    }
```

but then I got this error:

```
1) ExampleTest::testProductCreationFailsWhenNameNotProvided
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::seeJson() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\product-service\tests\ExampleTest.php on line 86
```

Comment: Did you change anything in your code based on the SO question you link to, because you're making the same mistake there that the poster of that question was making - passing an object rather than an array into `seeJson()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 + PHPunit - API test returns always invalid argument error foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921451/laravel-5-1-phpunit-api-test-returns-always-invalid-argument-error-foreach)

Comment: yes, I actually tried various combinations like -seeJson(json_encode(array('name' => ['The name field is required.']))) and a lot more

Comment: However, the official documentation says that the initial version was correct       https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#testing-json-apis

Comment: Just remove the [] from 'The name field is required.'

What response is the controller answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) ExampleTest::testProductCreationFailsWhenNameNotProvided
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::seeJson() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\product-service\tests\ExampleTest.php on line 86

This error tells you that you passed wrong type here:

```
->seeJson(json_encode(array('name' => ['The name field is required.'])))
```

You have to change it to look like this and it should work then.

```
->seeJson(array('name' => ['The name field is required.']))
```